# SQL Server DBMail post 1 October 2022 with Oauth 2.0 requirements

Tags: sql-server-2019, database-mail

I cannot get a straight answer from anyone on whether or not SQL Server mail will continue to work after 1 Oct with OAUTH 2.0 implementation by Microsoft. From what I understand  basic authentication will continue to work with SMTP meaning the we can continue to use mail in SQL server if we define a user/password.

I am not sure if OAUTH 2.0 can be implemented in SQL Server without using CLR.

Mike